# Weird normal map behavior

Tags: normal-map

Any idea why is there weird lighting around the silhouette of the object? A normal map baked from high poly version is applied on this low poly model.

These artefacts only occur on the silhouette.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either you forgot to set the [color space](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/textures/image.html#properties) of your image texture node to non-color data, either you obtained a normal map in DirectX format instead of OpenGL format, in which case you need to invert the Y channel of your normal map:
[image]